# What is the meaning of dots and dashes in kunyomi readings?

Tags: kanji, readings, punctuation, kana-usage

I was introduced to jisho.org a few days ago and I find it a really good tool to use while using the Heisig method to learn the readings as I learn the writing and understanding of kanji. I noticed 2 different symbols used when they present the kunyomi. So far I haven't seen them used in onyomi so I think they are not used in them. The "."(dot) and the "-"(dash). From what I gather I believe I got what they basically mean but please correct me if I'm wrong:

- "." - the dot is used to show where the kanji stops and after it the following is written in kana. I think the trailing kana had a name but I really can't remember it now. Is this **always** the case? When I see a dot should I always assume it's only kana after it? Or can there be kanji as well in some compounds?
- "-" - the dash is used to show that the word is allowed to form compounds only on the side where the dash is shown.

Take 一 for an example. Its 2 kun readings are: ひと-, ひと.つ so if I got this correctly:

一つ - this is how you write it according to the second reading.

Other thing I noticed is that there are times you can use a kanji instead of a trailing kana. I noticed this when I saw the other example compound on jisho 一月 Is this a common thing and does it have a term defining it so I can research further on my own?

一人 - this is really the only compound I could think of but the way I see it if the dash does what I think it does that means there will never be a compound word that has ひと somewhere elsewhere in the word apart from the beginning.

Comment: The trailing kana after the dot are called **okurigana** (送り仮名).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The upshot is that you should try to look at the explanatory notes of the dictionary you use and **try not to get too attached to a particular notation**. Knowing that *kanji* have a main reading, possibly with *okurigana* is usually all you need to know to make sense of a dictionary entry.

Here are some examples, which are frequently encountered:

- #### KANJIDIC

  The *kanji* search function on jisho.org uses [KANJIDIC](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/%7Ejwb/kanjidic.html) as its base. Indeed it looks as though the Western period `.` is used to separate the reading of the *kanji* from its *okurigana* and the Western hyphen `-` is used to indicate possible readings in compounds.
- #### Official list of *jōyō kanji*

  The official *jōyō kanji* list ([PDF](http://kokugo.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/joho/kijun/naikaku/pdf/joyokanjihyo_20101130.pdf)) published by the Agency of Cultural Affairs gives the readings as follows

  [image: 一]

  (no `.`, no `-`).
- #### Wikipedia

  Wikipedia uses a Western hyphen where KANJIDIC uses a Western period.
- #### Monolingual dictionaries

  Monolingual dictionaries usually list the word in *kana* and give *kanji* readings in brackets `【】`, e.g. *Daijirin* has

  > **ひと つ** [2] 【一つ】

  where a space was used between the *kanji* reading and the *okurigana*.
- #### Other dictionaries

  The *Shin Kanwa Daijiten* uses the *nakaguro* to separate the different readings and uses **`bold`** readings and `regular` *okurigana*:

  > ### 【一】
  >
  > **イチ**・**イツ**・**ひと**・**ひと**つ

---

As for compounds like 一月, these are either regular words (listed in a dictionary) or in this case [number]+[counter word], although you may also encounter other words like [word]+[suffix], of which only [word] and [suffix] are listed in the dictionary (and not the combination [word]+[suffix]).

---

As you suspected there are no *okurigana* for *on'yomi*. There are also no good rules for when which *on'yomi* gets read how, depending on position in a compound, so the notation `.` and `-` in KANJIDIC will only be used for *kun'yomi*.